# What are the scenes & monsters on the covers?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, content-identification

What are the scenes being portrayed on the covers of the *Player's Handbook* (PHB), *Dungeon Master's Guide* (DMG) and *Monster Manual* (MM) and what monsters do the scenes contain?

<sup>*(Click for larger images.)*</sup>
[image: Player's Handbook Cover]
[image: Dungeon Master's Guide Cover]
[image: Monster Manual Cover]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer can be found on page 2 of all books under the heading ***On the Cover*** accompanied by the full image of the cover.

---

The PHB reads:

> In this fiery scene illustrated by Tyler
> Jacobson, the fire giant King Snurre,
> suffering no fools to live, calls his hell
> hounds to join him in confronting
> unwelcome guests in his home.

The monster on the cover is a **Fire Giant** (MM p.154) accompanied by **Hell Hounds** (MM p.182).

King Snurre is…

> the final antagonist in the classic [Against the Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_the_Giants) modules. Originally used as tournament modules, they were published in 3 parts (G1, G2 and G3) in 1978 and then together (as G1-3) in 1981. The AD&D module G1-3 is [available at DMs Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/17037/G13-Against-the-Giants-1e?it=1) and a 5E conversion is part of [Tales from the Yawning Portal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tftyp). Versions were also published for other editions of AD&D and D&D.

---

The DMG reads:

> Tyler Jacobson illustrates the arch lich Acererak
> as he raises an army of undead and prepares to
> unleash it on an unsuspecting world.

The monster on the cover is a **Lich** (MM p.202).

Acerak is…

> the antagonist of the even-more-classic [Tomb of Horrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_Horrors) module. Also originally a tournament, it was first published as S1 in 1978. Like G1-3, it is [available at DMs Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/176871/S1-Tomb-of-Horrors-1e) and part of Tales from the Yawning Portal.
>
>  Acerak has been mentioned in many, many adventures over the last 30 years. Most recently, he is (perhaps) the power behind the [Tomb of Annihilation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa). Maybe. So much contradictory information has been written that it can't all be true. Can it?

---

The MM reads:

> Raymond Swan land illustrates the Xanathar
> ambushing explorers in the darkest depths
> of Undermountain, proving that the beholder
> crime lord's interests run deep beneath the
> city of Waterdeep.

The monster on the cover is a **Beholder** (MM p.28).

Xanathar the beholder is…

> the leader of the Xanathar Thieves' Guild in Skullport, as described in many sourcebooks and modules. The 5E book [Xanathar's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte) is said to be based on his research and knowledge.